# Why do my div elements scatter when I zoom in?

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:
When I don't zoom in, it looks like this:
[regular](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16UOO.gif)

But, When I zoom in, Instead of looking like one big rectangle like above, It looks like many small rectangles
[zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VYguN.gif)
Can someone help me make it so when I zoom in, it looks the same, just smaller? Thanks!

```css
.div {
 border-style: solid;
 display: inline-table;
 border-color: #91b8f7;
 vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 55%"><div style="float: left; width: 70%"><div style="display: block;"><h1 style=" display: inline-block; float: left;">RHT,  <span style="padding-left: 20px;">Red Hat Inc</span></h1><br><br><h1 style="float: left; font-size: 17px;">Red Hat, Inc. develops and provides open source software and services, including the Red Hat Linux operating system. The Companys web site offers information and news about open source software and provides an online community of open source software users and developers.</h1></div></div><div style="float: right; width: 30%"><h5><br></h5><h6 style="text-align: right">1801 Varsity Drive Raleigh, NC 27606 United States</h6><h5 style="text-align: right;">11,870 Employees</h5></div></div><div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 30%"><div style="float: left; padding-left: 20px;"><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Enterprise Value</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Market Cap</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Cash</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Total Debt</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Pref Equity</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Minority Int.</h4></div><div style="float: right; padding-right: 20px;"><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">29,583.28</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">31,288.21</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">2,472.93</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">768.00</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">0.00</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">0.00</h4></div></div><div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 15%"><div style="float: left; padding-left: 10px;"><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Shares Out</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Float %</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">SI</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">SI % Float</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Days to Cover</h4></div><div style="float: right; padding-right: 10px;"><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">177.1</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">99.4%</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">5.7</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">3.26%</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">3.37</h4></div></div>
<!-- new row -->
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 20%"><div style="padding-left: 20px;"><h3>Current Price: <span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="35">135.26</span>    <span style="color: red"><span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($dataRed)" data-reactid="36">-1.06 (-0.78%)</span></span></h3><h4>Today Date / Time:   07/04/2018 07:09 pm</h4><h4>YTD Return:  45.7%</h4></div></div><div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 11%"><div style="float: left; padding-left: 10px;"><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">52 Week Hi/Low</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">52 Week Return</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Month Return</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Month Return</h5></div><div style="float: right; padding-right: 10px;"><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">88.75</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">99.2%</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">35.9%</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">8.6%</h5></div></div><div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 10%"><div style="float: left; padding-left: 20px;"><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">PE</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">EV/EBITDA</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">P/S</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">P/B</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Div Yield</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Beta</h5></div><div style="float: right; padding-right: 20px;"><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">70.2x</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">42.8x</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">8.9x</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">17.8x</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">0.0%</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">85.2</h5></div></div><div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 59%"><div style="float: left; padding-left: 10px;"><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Valuation</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Thesis</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Catalysts</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Risks</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Actions</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Current Exp</h5></div><div style="float: right; padding-right: 10px;"><h5 style="line-height: 20px;"><span id="a">Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo m...</span><div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. </p>
  </div>

</div></h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;"><span id="b">I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this sto...</span><div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock.I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock.I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock.I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock.I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock.</p>
  </div>

</div></h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;"><span id="c">sdf...</span><div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>sdf</p>
  </div>

</div></h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;"><span id="d">sdfdsf...</span><div id="myModal3" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>sdfdsf</p>
  </div>

</div></h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;"><span id="e">my name is matthew, I will work on the modal box tommorow...</span><div id="myModal4" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>my name is matthew, I will work on the modal box tommorow</p>
  </div>

</div></h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;"><span id="f">123...</span><div id="myModal5" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>123</p>
  </div>

</div></h5></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code below is I think what you want. I simply added classes such as table, table-row, and table-cell to your divs.

Also, just would like to point out that the snippet you provided does not produce the same result as the image your link provides. Lastly, there are a lot of tools online to help format your code (e.g. https://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html).

Hope this helps!

```css
.div {
 border-style: solid;
 display: table-cell;
 border-color: #91b8f7;
 vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div style="display:table;">

<div style="display:table-row;">
   <div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 55%">
      <div style="float: left; width: 70%">
         <div style="display: block;">
            <h1 style=" display: inline-block; float: left;">RHT,  <span style="padding-left: 20px;">Red Hat Inc</span></h1>
            <br><br>
            <h1 style="float: left; font-size: 17px;">Red Hat, Inc. develops and provides open source software and services, including the Red Hat Linux operating system. The Companys web site offers information and news about open source software and provides an online community of open source software users and developers.</h1>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div style="float: right; width: 30%">
         <h5><br></h5>
         <h6 style="text-align: right">1801 Varsity Drive Raleigh, NC 27606 United States</h6>
         <h5 style="text-align: right;">11,870 Employees</h5>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 30%">
      <div style="float: left; padding-left: 20px;">
         <h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Enterprise Value</h4>
         <h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Market Cap</h4>
         <h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Cash</h4>
         <h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Total Debt</h4>
         <h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Pref Equity</h4>
         <h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Minority Int.</h4>
      </div>
      <div style="float: right; padding-right: 20px;">
         <h4 style="line-height: 20px;">29,583.28</h4>
         <h4 style="line-height: 20px;">31,288.21</h4>
         <h4 style="line-height: 20px;">2,472.93</h4>
         <h4 style="line-height: 20px;">768.00</h4>
         <h4 style="line-height: 20px;">0.00</h4>
         <h4 style="line-height: 20px;">0.00</h4>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 15%">
      <div style="float: left; padding-left: 10px;">
         <h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Shares Out</h4>
         <h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Float %</h4>
         <h4 style="line-height: 20px;">SI</h4>
         <h4 style="line-height: 20px;">SI % Float</h4>
         <h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Days to Cover</h4>
      </div>
      <div style="float: right; padding-right: 10px;">
         <h4 style="line-height: 20px;">177.1</h4>
         <h4 style="line-height: 20px;">99.4%</h4>
         <h4 style="line-height: 20px;">5.7</h4>
         <h4 style="line-height: 20px;">3.26%</h4>
         <h4 style="line-height: 20px;">3.37</h4>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- new row -->

<div style="display:table;">
<div style="display: table-row;">
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 20%">
   <div style="padding-left: 20px;">
      <h3>Current Price: <span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="35">135.26</span>    <span style="color: red"><span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($dataRed)" data-reactid="36">-1.06 (-0.78%)</span></span></h3>
      <h4>Today Date / Time:   07/04/2018 07:09 pm</h4>
      <h4>YTD Return:  45.7%</h4>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 11%">
   <div style="float: left; padding-left: 10px;">
      <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">52 Week Hi/Low</h5>
      <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">52 Week Return</h5>
      <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Month Return</h5>
      <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Month Return</h5>
   </div>
   <div style="float: right; padding-right: 10px;">
      <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">88.75</h5>
      <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">99.2%</h5>
      <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">35.9%</h5>
      <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">8.6%</h5>
   </div>
</div>
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 10%">
   <div style="float: left; padding-left: 20px;">
      <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">PE</h5>
      <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">EV/EBITDA</h5>
      <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">P/S</h5>
      <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">P/B</h5>
      <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Div Yield</h5>
      <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Beta</h5>
   </div>
   <div style="float: right; padding-right: 20px;">
      <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">70.2x</h5>
      <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">42.8x</h5>
      <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">8.9x</h5>
      <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">17.8x</h5>
      <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">0.0%</h5>
      <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">85.2</h5>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 59%">
<div style="float: left; padding-left: 10px;">
   <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Valuation</h5>
   <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Thesis</h5>
   <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Catalysts</h5>
   <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Risks</h5>
   <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Actions</h5>
   <h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Current Exp</h5>
</div>
<div style="float: right; padding-right: 10px;">
<h5 style="line-height: 20px;">
   <span id="a">Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo m...</span>
   <div id="myModal" class="modal">
      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
         <span class="close">×</span>
         <p>Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. </p>
      </div>
   </div>
</h5>
<h5 style="line-height: 20px;">
   <span id="b">I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this sto...</span>
   <div id="myModal1" class="modal">
      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
         <span class="close">×</span>
         <p>I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock.I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock.I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock.I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock.I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock.</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</h5>
<h5 style="line-height: 20px;">
   <span id="c">sdf...</span>
   <div id="myModal2" class="modal">
      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
         <span class="close">×</span>
         <p>sdf</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</h5>
<h5 style="line-height: 20px;">
   <span id="d">sdfdsf...</span>
   <div id="myModal3" class="modal">
      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
         <span class="close">×</span>
         <p>sdfdsf</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</h5>
<h5 style="line-height: 20px;">
   <span id="e">my name is matthew, I will work on the modal box tommorow...</span>
   <div id="myModal4" class="modal">
      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
         <span class="close">×</span>
         <p>my name is matthew, I will work on the modal box tommorow</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</h5>
<h5 style="line-height: 20px;">
   <span id="f">123...</span>
   <div id="myModal5" class="modal">
      <!-- Modal content -->
      <div class="modal-content">
         <span class="close">×</span>
         <p>123</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</h5>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not render like shown on the picture. You should use a grid system to produce a more responsive version of what your trying to make. As for just making all the content in the boxes fit, I added {padding: 1rem} to the .div

```css
.div {
 border-style: solid;
 display: inline-table;
 border-color: #91b8f7;
 vertical-align: top;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 55%"><div style="float: left; width: 70%"><div style="display: block;"><h1 style=" display: inline-block; float: left;">RHT,  <span style="padding-left: 20px;">Red Hat Inc</span></h1><br><br><h1 style="float: left; font-size: 17px;">Red Hat, Inc. develops and provides open source software and services, including the Red Hat Linux operating system. The Companys web site offers information and news about open source software and provides an online community of open source software users and developers.</h1></div></div><div style="float: right; width: 30%"><h5><br></h5><h6 style="text-align: right">1801 Varsity Drive Raleigh, NC 27606 United States</h6><h5 style="text-align: right;">11,870 Employees</h5></div></div><div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 30%"><div style="float: left; padding-left: 20px;"><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Enterprise Value</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Market Cap</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Cash</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Total Debt</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Pref Equity</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Minority Int.</h4></div><div style="float: right; padding-right: 20px;"><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">29,583.28</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">31,288.21</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">2,472.93</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">768.00</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">0.00</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">0.00</h4></div></div><div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 15%"><div style="float: left; padding-left: 10px;"><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Shares Out</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Float %</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">SI</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">SI % Float</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">Days to Cover</h4></div><div style="float: right; padding-right: 10px;"><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">177.1</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">99.4%</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">5.7</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">3.26%</h4><h4 style="line-height: 20px;">3.37</h4></div></div>
<!-- new row -->
<div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 20%"><div style="padding-left: 20px;"><h3>Current Price: <span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(b) Fz(36px) Mb(-4px) D(ib)" data-reactid="35">135.26</span>    <span style="color: red"><span class="Trsdu(0.3s) Fw(500) Pstart(10px) Fz(24px) C($dataRed)" data-reactid="36">-1.06 (-0.78%)</span></span></h3><h4>Today Date / Time:   07/04/2018 07:09 pm</h4><h4>YTD Return:  45.7%</h4></div></div><div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 11%"><div style="float: left; padding-left: 10px;"><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">52 Week Hi/Low</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">52 Week Return</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Month Return</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Month Return</h5></div><div style="float: right; padding-right: 10px;"><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">88.75</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">99.2%</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">35.9%</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">8.6%</h5></div></div><div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 10%"><div style="float: left; padding-left: 20px;"><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">PE</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">EV/EBITDA</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">P/S</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">P/B</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Div Yield</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Beta</h5></div><div style="float: right; padding-right: 20px;"><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">70.2x</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">42.8x</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">8.9x</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">17.8x</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">0.0%</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">85.2</h5></div></div><div class="div" style="height: 200px; width: 59%"><div style="float: left; padding-left: 10px;"><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Valuation</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Thesis</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Catalysts</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Risks</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Actions</h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;">Current Exp</h5></div><div style="float: right; padding-right: 10px;"><h5 style="line-height: 20px;"><span id="a">Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo m...</span><div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. Helllo my name is bob. </p>
  </div>

</div></h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;"><span id="b">I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this sto...</span><div id="myModal1" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock.I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock.I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock.I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock.I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock. I really like this stock.</p>
  </div>

</div></h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;"><span id="c">sdf...</span><div id="myModal2" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>sdf</p>
  </div>

</div></h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;"><span id="d">sdfdsf...</span><div id="myModal3" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>sdfdsf</p>
  </div>

</div></h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;"><span id="e">my name is matthew, I will work on the modal box tommorow...</span><div id="myModal4" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>my name is matthew, I will work on the modal box tommorow</p>
  </div>

</div></h5><h5 style="line-height: 20px;"><span id="f">123...</span><div id="myModal5" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">×</span>
    <p>123</p>
  </div>

</div></h5></div></div>
```